# compatibility of gevent with other packages

Tags: python, compatibility, gevent

In short, my question is: how do I know when some particular Python package is compatible with gevent (at least with gevent.monkey.patch_all)?

Actually I was wondering if [http-parser](https://github.com/benoitc/http-parser) library is compatible with gevent (will it block all eventlets somewhere or not), but having a general answer will be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the library you want to use is built using something that [`gevent.monkey.patch_all()`](http://www.gevent.org/intro.html#monkey-patching) patches, then it will *probably* work.

`patch_all()` will make the *standard library* play nice with gevent. For example, the socket module is part of the standard library and is patched by `patch_all()` or `patch_socket()`, thus any library that is built using sockets *should probably maybe work*.

It would seem like [http-parser](https://github.com/benoitc/http-parser) uses the socket module, and should thus be compatible with gevent. The only way to know for sure is to test.

Here's an example test, implemented from the example of http-parser github:

```
from gevent.monkey import patch_all; patch_all()
from gevent.socket import create_connection
import gevent
from http_parser.http import HttpStream
from http_parser.reader import SocketReader

def worker(n):
    try:
        s = create_connection(('gunicorn.org', 80))
        s.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: gunicorn.org\r\n\r\n")
        r = SocketReader(s)
        p = HttpStream(r)
        print "Worker {}, headers length: {}".format(n, len(p.headers()))
    finally:
        s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = [gevent.spawn(worker, job_no) for job_no in range(10)]
    gevent.joinall(jobs)
```

Which outputs:

```
(test)msvalkon@Lunkwill:/tmp$ python test_http_parser.py 
Worker 8, headers length: 4
Worker 1, headers length: 4
Worker 5, headers length: 10
Worker 2, headers length: 10
Worker 9, headers length: 10
Worker 4, headers length: 10
Worker 3, headers length: 10
Worker 6, headers length: 10
Worker 7, headers length: 10
Worker 0, headers length: 10
```

It seems that [`http-parser`](https://github.com/benoitc/http-parser) is compliant with gevent.

Comment: Warning to others who is interested: **http_parser turned out to be not compliant with gevent when using with default settings**. The thing is, it has two implementations: pure Python (which supports gevent), and C (which is not). http_parser tries to use the second one when possible. I ended up with patching http_parser/http.py to always import pyparser